# Java Strange integer format

Tags: java

I encountered this question and wasn't quite sure what this means

```
int birthDate.month()=IO.readInt();
```

Why can a method be used in an integer? And what does that mean?

Comment: haven't seen sucha code like this in java yet, interesting.

Comment: What is `IO` supposed to be? And why the `()` after month?

Comment: Method calls cannot be used as lvalues in assignments, this code will not compile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> And what does that mean?

It means that the author wasn't writing valid Java, and wasn't compiling their code.  This won't work.